# Change the Triage Upvote Animation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, triage, user-interface

This is a very minor point but it affects people's perception of how to use Triage and what it should involve, assuming some amount of other people do read it the same as me.

When a 'Looks Ok' consensus is established in Triage, the voting markers will appear and prompt the user to vote on the question if it does indeed look ok. My issue is that it shakes vigorously, as if indicating that the user should have already done this. It ends up feeling like its chastising the reviewer for not taking a step, even though it's not actually possible until after they've clicked that button. I'm not reaching for this interpretation by the way, it did confuse me for a while when I was new to reviewing and I didn't realise that upvoting in Triage was only available after consensus.

I believe the point of the animation on it is to catch the reviewer's eye so they'll see that the option to vote has now appeared, however a smaller amount of animation can do this job perfectly well without also seeming to indicate a mistake has been made and needs to be corrected.

Comment: I totally just [marked a random question as OK just to see the animation](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8304577). No ragrets. (I mean, it doesn't seem to be in *dire* need for improvement...)

Comment: Anyway, I agree that the animation is particularly jarring.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, it's not dire. I was debating if it was worthwhile to post, then saw someone making the case for changing to denote millions with an uppercase M instead of lowercase, so I figured it was worth it.

Comment: Oh I was referring to the question I reviewed, not the animation.

Comment: I'd be in favour of simply removing the upvote nagging. It's well documented that triage reviews are more based on luck than on the quality of the post (too many people click "looks OK" on total crap, most users have no idea what "should be improved" actually does), and thus it's heavily debatable if a question that was reviewed as OK is actually decent. Furthermore, nagging people to upvote questions that "look OK" feels inherently wrong as questions shouldn't be upvoted just because they're not crap, but because they're _useful, clear, and show research effort_.